# how to check if a value inside an array is larger than a certain value

Tags: arrays, if-statement

alright so my question is probably stupid and I don't even know if it can be done but I have inserted some elements into an array through scanner, and I have put it through a certain calculation . The calculation results are also stored inside another array. what I want to do is to see if these calculated values are larger than 0. I want these calculated values to be printed along side the + or - sign. so what I was thinking is to have 2 sets of printing statements where if the sign value of the calculated amount is >0 it will proceed a print statement where as if it is <0 it will proceed another print statement. But I don't know how to check if a element inside array is larger or smaller than zero.  Spare my explanation I tried my best to not make it hard to understand.

so lets say the user inputs 14. which would then go through the calculation process and store 2 inside the array.[(14-10)/2]. so since this is bigger than zero , i want a print statement to execute in a way that i can get +2 as the answer.

assume the user enters 8. which would go through the calculation process and store -2[(8-10)/2], and since -2 is stored here it is <0 and there for i want a separate statement to get executed.

My issue is i dont know how to check if a element inside an array is 0 or not. there are 5 elements inside the array and i want to check if all of them are above or below zero and print different statements for each. 
thank you so much in advance.I am using java btw.

```
    int[] bonus=new int[6]; // this is used to store the keyboard entries

    if(bonus[]<0) {       //used this to check the condition and if the conditon            
    System.out.println(level);
    System.out.println("your str=" + bonus[0]); 

   else{System.out.println("your str=+" +bonus[0]);
       }
```

bonus is the arrayName i have used and 0 is the first slot in which the value entered through keyboard for str is stored after the calculation process.Note:there are few coding prior to that including the array executions which i have not stated hoping this would be enough

Comment: What language are you using? What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get through this using a for loop i and iterating through it i managed to check if they were 0 and/or above .Thank you for those who read and tried to go through this